# Groovy Installation

Tags: groovy

I tried to install groovy in windows 7.
I Downloaded archive from groovy site.
Unzip it. 
Add `GROOVY_HOME` path to environment.
Add bin path to environment.
After that I rebooted windows.
But when I try to run groovy from cmd I get error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter

Answer (score 8):

You may have directories of other Groovy versions in your path. If you have installed Groovy before (may be years ago - doesn't matter), check your environment variables, especially `PATH`, for other Groovy distributions.

The file `%GROOVY_HOME%/conf/groovy-starter.conf` gives some more hints of what actually happens while starting the binaries. Having this in mind, the cause of your problem may be the usage of the wrong binaries. That may result in the expectation of other classes or class names than provided by the up to date `GROOVY_HOME` directories - eventually yielding your error.

Check all your paths twice for this.

UPDATE:

I accidentally just ran into that problem because I was messing around with Groovy-versions (just as I told you not to ;)).
Here is an easy hint how to find out if all paths are correct (for Windows).

1. Open your Command-Shell with `cmd`.
2. Type in `set DEBUG=true` to activate the Debug-Statements.
3. Type in `groovysh` (requesting the interactive Groovy-shell).
4. Have a look at the last lines where "java.exe" is called. There is a long statement containing all resolved path dependencies. Check if these all contain your correct distribution, for instance, "groovy-2.4.4.jar".

cheers

Comment: The GROOVY_HOME environment variable had been set to an old installation in our case - thanks

Answer (score 7):

1. You just need to set `GROOVY_HOME` to your Groovy directory, for example:

   ```
   GROOVY_HOME=C:\groovy\groovy-2.4.6
   ```
2. And `JAVA_HOME` to JRE
3. Make sure that both `GROOVY_HOME/bin` and `JAVA_HOME/bin` are available in your `PATH`

Comment: Don't forget to restart the terminal (close /reopen)

Answer (score 4):

According to their webside [install on windows](http://www.groovy-lang.org/install.html#_installation_on_windows) maybe you don't have java `HOME` path set:

> Set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to your JDK. On OS X this is `/Library/Java/Home`, on other unixes it's often `/usr/java`, etc. If you’ve already installed tools like Ant or Maven you’ve probably already done this step.

Could you also provide your `GROOVY_HOME` path and system `PATH` - maybe you did some typo.

Comment: Java_Home is present.

Comment: GROOVY_HOME - D:\groovy-2.4.4
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
variables from PATH - "D:\groovy-2.4.4\bin";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin"

Comment: Paths looks good. My last shot would be files and dirs user permissions - maybe you're lack of them.

Comment: I start cmd with administrator permission

Comment: According to this topic: http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td362496 for some reasons spaces, parentheses and dots can cause a problem. Try to sanitize your path to D:\groovy244

Comment: Tha same problem.
I tried to run groovy from bin path and there is the same error

Comment: I don't any other idea :( Please write what you've tried in question (those information from our comments), maybe it will trigger somebody to help you with an issue

Answer (score 3):

Variable name: `GROOVY_HOME` 
Variable Value: `C:\Program Files\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.14\groovy-2.4.14`

in the PATH 
`%GROOVY_HOME%`

This is what worked for me.

Comment: This wont effect your groovy issue but it will effect your other PATH variables in the fact that you are exporting PATH TWICE. Only export PATH once; I have run into issues with exporting path twice and having multiple variables on the path. You dont want this.

Answer (score 2):

Open a command line and test your paths with echo.

```
echo %path%
echo %JAVA_HOME%
echo %GROOVY_HOME%
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add java path in the `./bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
export GROOVY_HOME=/Users/magic/Library/Develop-Tools/groovy-2.5.8/

export PATH=${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH=${PATH}:$GROOVY_HOME/bin
```

According to the [official document](http://groovy-lang.org/install.html)

[image]